# ¿Cómo al presionar el boton cerrar por defecto de una activity (el de la X que aparece en la parte superior) enviarle un mensaje al usuario?

Tags: java, android-studio

quiero utilizar el boton por defecto no quiero crear un boton y poner finish o onPressed(). Porfa:

Quiero decir, el activity esta en primer plano, listo. Luego quiero cerrarlo entonces presiono el boton cuadradito del telefono:[image: lO QUE quiero representar]
Y Quiero indicar al usuario "antes de salir guarde los datos." y que no salga o no cierre la aplicación.

TALVES EXISTA UN METODO AL CUAL LO TENGO QUE SOBREESCRIBIR

Comment: Ud. debería guardar sus datos cuando se dispare el evento onPause().

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("onPause","finish");

}
```

Antes de abandonar la actividad realice la notificación.

Comment: No, esto es pára la aplicación no para una tarea.